# I am new to vue and I can seem to get a response for this.$http.get('url', function(data)) in Vue

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

I am using am new to laravel(5.2) and vue. I am trying to pass data to a view from a database. It appears that my right route is fine and I get some json data response but I am having trouble logging the data to console or my view. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my ShowEvent component stored in a .vue file

```
<template>

<div class="events_list">
    <h1> My Events </h1>

    <ul class="list-group">

        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="event in list">
            {{ event.body}}

        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {


    data: function () {
        return {


            list: []

        };

    },

    created: function(){

        this.fetchEventsList();



    },

    methods: {
        fetchEventsList: function () {
            this.$http.get('/api/events', function(data){

                console.log(data);

            });

        },

        delete: function(event) {
            this.list.$remove(event);

        }
    }


}
```

Here is my main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);
import ShowEvent from  './components/ShowEvent.vue';



new Vue({

el: '#app',

components: {ShowEvent: ShowEvent},

ready(){


        alert("Ready to go!, Show Events");


}

});
```

And this is the the view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Eventer</title>
</head>


<body>

<div id="app" class="container">

<show-event>

</show-event>

</div>


<script src="/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add a callback for failure in your request, you should not suppose that everything works fine during the request

Comment: Also, what version of vue-resource are you using, your syntax is wrong in the current version

Comment: I am using vue 1.0.26 and vue-resource 0.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your call with:

```
this.$http.get('/api/events').then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data) 
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

[Check the docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md) for more info